# Adding a Vue.js v-bind:style attribute to an element that is dynamically created after page load

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, vue.js

First of all, to understand my problems and choices: I am translating an existing JS project into a Vue.js framework.

I am struggeling with a problem that is easy to solve in jQuery but is breaking my head in Vue.js

In my code I have to generate canvasses after the whole page is loaded and then add them to a canvas container div. I need to make a change to the CSS of all of these canvasses when I click a button. The canvasses are as of now added using `document.createElement('canvas')`.

The Vue way would be to add a `v-bind:style` attribute to the canvas and change it by setting a variable in `data()` the vue JS code, something like this: `<canvas v-bind:style="{width: customWidth}></canvas>"` and `<button v-on:click="customWidth++">+</button>`.

What I understand so far is that if I add the `v-bind:style` attribute whilst generating a canvas in the following way: `canvas.setAttribute('v-bind:style', '{width: customWidth}')`, Vue.js will not be aware of it's existance, since it was generated after loading up the page.

I am looking for a suggestion on how to solve my problem.

So, just to illustrate, this:

```
<div id="canvas-container"><div>
<button v-on:click="customWidth++">+</button>
<button v-on:click="customWidth--">-</button>
```

should become this:

```
<div id="canvas-container">
   <canvas v-bind:style="{width: customWidth}"></canvas>
   <canvas v-bind:style="{width: customWidth}"></canvas>
   <canvas v-bind:style="{width: customWidth}"></canvas>
   <canvas v-bind:style="{width: customWidth}"></canvas>
   <canvas v-bind:style="{width: customWidth}"></canvas>
<div>
<button v-on:click="customWidth++">+</button>
<button v-on:click="customWidth--">-</button>
```

With this in the Vue JS code:

```
data(){
   return{
      customWidth: 100
   }
}
```

And be responsive to the button

Comment: What determines how many canvases are in the container? Use `v-for` to iterate over that.

Comment: I agree with Bert, vue'ify the whole thing and use `v-for` to create the canvases. If that is a problem, just use pure JS `document.querySelector('#canvas-container canvas')` and add the style that way.

Comment: @webnoob This works for me, thank you for pointing me in that direction. I agree that it is more correct to Vueify the whole thing, but this is a good temporary solution!

Comment: @fluffypirate Fair enough - if only we had all the time in world eh? :) I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vue'ify the whole thing and using a `v-for` to create the canvases would be ideal but if that is a problem, just use pure JS

```
document.querySelector('#canvas-container canvas')
```

and add the style that way.